# How to center a div inside another div that has 100% width?

Tags: html, css

How can I horizontally center a div that's inside another div which has 100% width?

```css
#conteudo{
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff7db url(../_img/content-border.jpg) repeat-x ;
  min-height: 1080px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#principal{
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="conteudo">
    <section id="principal">
      <img src="_img/summer-nymph.png" alt="summer-nymph.png">

        <p>
          Nullam sed magna mattis, posuere enim nec, fermentum risus.
          Aenean diam massa, condimentum id urna in, porta laoreet tortor.
          Duis tempus vitae risus nec hendrerit. Fusce euismod ligula id erat dignissim,
          nec viverra ante condimentum. Phasellus sollicitudin tincidunt lectus id luctus.
        </p>
    </section>
  </div>
```

I want to center `div#principal` horizontally inside `div#conteudo` but my code isn't working.

Comment: Isn't it centered already?

Comment: @slashsharp no. it's not working

Comment: In your snippet the block is ALREADY centered. So you need to check your styles. Or you can show us your full HTML and CSS code.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is centered horizontally. If you really want it centered horizontally then there must be something wrong in the codelines you haven't posted. One common mistake would be a wrong link to your css file. I did this mistake a lot of times so I recommend you checking your link tag to your CSS file in the head of your HTML code
If it isn't your link tag, then you need to post the whole code for further help.

I misread the question earlier on (mixed up horizontal and vertical), but still I want to leave this in because it might be helpful and it might help
you with future centering problems:
You can also center a div with the css flexbox layout mode

Here is a snippet of how it looks like:

```css
#conteudo {
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff7db url(../_img/content-border.jpg) repeat-x ;
  min-height: 1080px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;

  /*
  Center a div horizontally and vertically with the flexbox
  If you only want it centered in one direction, just remove
  the other property
  */
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center; /* horizontal center */
  align-items:center; /* vertical center */
}

#principal{
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="conteudo">
    <section id="principal">
      <img src="_img/summer-nymph.png" alt="summer-nymph.png">

      <p>
        Nullam sed magna mattis, posuere enim nec, fermentum risus.
        Aenean diam massa, condimentum id urna in, porta laoreet tortor.
        Duis tempus vitae risus nec hendrerit. Fusce euismod ligula id erat dignissim,
        nec viverra ante condimentum. Phasellus sollicitudin tincidunt lectus id luctus.
      </p>
      
    </section>
</div>
```

However this solution doesn't work on very old browsers (IE 9 and older) but it works on almost every modern browser. Still the flexbox is a really good layout mode of css. I really recommend taking a look at it.

You can check out this link to a flexbox guide:
[Flexbox Guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)